# WPF anchor Grid OpacityMask for Moving Grid Content

Tags: wpf, opacitymask

I have a hexagonal `Polygon` that I am trying to use as an `OpacityMask`, then have content inside the polygon that can scroll and be clipped at the edges. The problem I encounter is that as the content moves, the `OpacityMask` moves with it (though by a different amount).  Below is my code:

```
<Window Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Height="450" Width="800">
        <StackPanel>
        <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
        <Grid.OpacityMask >
            <VisualBrush Stretch="None" >
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Polygon Points="220,225 310,69 490,69 580,225 490, 381 310, 381" Fill="Black" />
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Grid.OpacityMask>
        <Polygon Points="220,225 310,69 490,69 580,225 490, 381 310, 381" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="TestRectangle" Height="400" Width="400" Fill="Red" />
        </Grid>
            <Button Content="Testing" >
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TestRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                    BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5" To="-400,0,0,0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How do I anchor the opacity mask so that the grid content can move with the mask remaining stationary?

Edit: Answer Results and Additional Testing

Using the code in an answer provided, I still get movement of the hexagon:

Begin:
[Begin State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty8a1.jpg)
End:
[End State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8MON.jpg)

However, I have found that by adding a second rectangle that is transparent and that moves in the opposite direction of the red rectangle, I achieve the desired result. While this does work, it seems like there should be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to set the margin of the rectangle directly, you would notice that it is ignored inside a grid. So one way to solve that would be to put the rectangle inside a border and animate the margin for that border

```
<Window x:Class="StackverflowTests.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackverflowTests"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Height="450" Width="810">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
            <Grid.OpacityMask >
                <VisualBrush Stretch="None" >
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <Polygon Points="220,225 310,69 490,69 580,225 490, 381 310, 381" Fill="Black" />
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Grid.OpacityMask>
            <Polygon Points="220,225 310,69 490,69 580,225 490, 381 310, 381" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5"/>
            <Border x:Name="TestRectangle">
                <Rectangle Height="400" Width="400" Fill="#ff0000"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
        <Button Content="Testing" >
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TestRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                        BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5" To="-400,0,0,0" AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Using this code, the hexagon still moves with the rectangle. My goal is to have the polygon remain stationary so that it is effectively a clipping mask for the content (in this case rectangle).

Comment: yes i understand, actually running this code i can see the red area moving, however the hexagonal representing the mask remains stationary. (tested it against .net core 3.1 and .net framework 4.6)

Comment: the hexagon still moves to the left for me. I am running it in .net framework 4.6.1. It starts with the hexagon in the center and at the end of the animation (discounting the autoreverse), the hexagon's left margin is reduced by about half.